# While loop doesn't output next instance of substring

Tags: c++

I have the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string file = "words.txt";
    std::string word;
    std::ifstream inFile;
    std::string delimiter = ",";
    inFile.open(file);
    if (!inFile){
        std::cerr << "File not opened." << std::endl;
    }
    while (getline(inFile, word)){
        std::cout << word.substr(0, word.find(delimiter)) << " ";
        word.erase(0, word.find(delimiter) + delimiter.length());
    }
    inFile.close();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

with a problem in this loop:

```
    while (getline(inFile, word)){
        std::cout << word.substr(0, word.find(delimiter)) << " ";
        word.erase(0, word.find(delimiter) + delimiter.length());
    }
```

The only output I receive is the first substring of the form `"word1"` in the output.

I have typed in a `std::cout << word.substr(0, word.find(delimiter))` in the line after the erase function to determine if the word still has characters, and it indeed does. `word` is a very long string in the form `"word1","word2","word3",...,"lastword"` and my delimiter is `","`.

Comment: You're iterating over lines in the file, not over words in the line. Do `getline(inFile, word, ',')` instead, but then you don't need to do any `substr` business. If you need to iterate over both lines and words in those lines, you're going to need nested loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @[Joseph Mansfield](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150634/joseph-mansfield) said in the comment . you are iterating thorough the line of file not words of it .

For splitting words by  `,` you can simply use delimiter  as the third input of `getline`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string file = "words.txt";
    std::string word;
    std::ifstream inFile;
    char delimiter = ',';
    inFile.open(file);
    if (!inFile){
        std::cerr << "File not opened." << std::endl;
    }
    while (getline(inFile, word,delimiter)){
        std::cout << word << " ";
    }
    inFile.close();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

And for reading multiple lines :

```
std::string line;
while (getline(inFile, line)){
    std::stringstream stream(line); 
    while (getline(stream, word, delimiter)){
        std::cout << word << " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the condition of the while you're reading the next line with *getline(inFile, word)*. Therefore *word* does now contain the next read **line**.